# If I draw the variable "m" from M~N(0, 1), then draw "x" from N(m, 1), what is the distribution of "X" (not X|M)

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, normal-distribution

**Step 1:**

I draw the observation "m" from M~N(0, 1) (i.e. a Normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1)

**Step 2:**

Then I draw "x" from N(m, 1) (i.e. a Normal distribution centered in m)

**My question:**

What is the distribution of "X"? Is it still a Normal (0, 1) ? I honestly don't think so. While I do believe the mean is still 0, I feel like the variance should increase!

It is okay if the distribution is not a known one, just I'd love to see the steps to get to that distribution! Thanks!

**Step where I’m stuck:**

I do not know which are the steps to compute the distribution of x. How to obtain the density function of x?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I run an experiment with python and found something interesting empirically, but do not know how to formalize

And I found out that doing my experiment as written above yields a distribution very very similar (or maybe exactly that) of N(0, s2 * 3 / 2)

here is the code

```py
# You can use any value for the variance here, the figures still overlap almost perfectly

s_2 = 40

def get_simple_normal():
    return np.random.normal(0, s_2 * 3 / 2)

def get_compound_normal():
    new_mean = np.random.normal(0, s_2)
    
    return np.random.normal(new_mean, s_2)

# Generate 10 million datapoints
n = 10000000

data = {
    'simple_normal': [get_simple_normal() for _ in range(n)],
    'compound_normal': [get_compound_normal() for _ in range(n)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot the data

plt.hist(df['simple_normal'], bins=10000, alpha=0.3, color='red', label='simple normal N(0, s_2 * 3 / 2)')
plt.hist(df['compound_normal'], bins=10000, alpha=0.3, color='blue', label='compound normal N(0, s_2)')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You are correct to think the mean is still $0$ and the variance increases.  Another way to look at it is to suppose $M \sim N(0,1)$ and independently $Y \sim N(0,1)$, with $X=M+Y$.

Comment: mmmm thanks for the input @Henry but the thing is that I am not sure that M and Y are independent random variables

Comment: Your model assumes they would be independent.  But it has a couple of issues: `s_2` is the "[scale](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)", i.e. the standard deviation = the square root of the variance, rather than the variance; and you would get a better fit using $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.414$ rather than $3/2=1.5$

Comment: $X=M+Y$ with $M, Y$ independent because $N(M, 1)=M+N(0,1)$

Comment: You can verify the assertions by Henry and Ute simply by replacing your line `return np.random.normal(new_mean, s_2)` by `return np.random.normal(0, s_2) + new_mean` and verifying the results are *identical.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F_X(x) = P(X \le x) = \int P(X \le x|M=m) d P_M(m) = \int \Phi(x-m) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{m^2}{2}}dm$$
So the density is:
$$f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_X(x) =  \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{m^2}{2}}dm = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(\frac{x}{2} - m)^2}dm = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}$$ so $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$

Answer (score 1):

**This is a consequence of a general result in regression.**

#### Background

Suppose generally $M$ is a random variable with characteristic function

$$\chi_M(t) = E\left[e^{iMt}\right]$$

and the conditional distribution of $X-M$ has characteristic function

$$\chi_{X-M\mid M}(t) = E\left[e^{i(X-M)t}\mid M\right] = E\left[e^{iXt}\mid M\right]e^{-iMt}.\tag{*}$$

**Suppose $X$ equals $M$ plus a random term whose distribution does not vary with $M.$** That is equivalent to assuming *the conditional characteristic function on the left of $(*)$ does not depend on $M.$* Then the tower law of conditional expectation and the linearity of expectation show the characteristic function of $X$ is

> $$\begin{aligned}
> \chi_X(t) &= E\left[e^{iXt}\right] = E\left[E\left[e^{iXt}\mid M\right]\right] =  E\left[\chi_{X-M\mid M}(t) e^{-iMt}\right]\\
> & = \chi_{X-M\mid M}(t)\chi_M(t).
> \end{aligned}$$

---

#### Solution

The question posits that

$$\chi_M(t) = e^{-t^2/2} = \chi_{X-M\mid M}(t), $$

whence

$$\chi_X(t) = e^{-t^2/2} e^{-t^2/2} = e^{-2t^2/2},$$

which is the characteristic function of the Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $2.$